# Cross compilation with clang

Tags: c++, linux, arm

I am attempting to cross compile a program from an x86_64 linux machine to arm 64-bit (aarch64) format. The file that I am attempting to cross-compile uses OpenCV. I am able to successfully cross-compile programs that don't include external libraries, but when I include OpenCV I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_shape.so.3.2.0: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
clang-6.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [helloworld] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/helloworld.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is /usr/local/lib/libopencv_shape.so compiled for arm ?

Comment: What output of `file  /usr/local/lib/libopencv_shape.so`?

Comment: No, it is not compiled for ARM; is that necessary for cross compilation? In that is it possible to cross compile x86 binaries to arm?